# Check if VLC is installed

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, registry, vlc

I'm calling vlc from a C# app in order to play a video. I need a way to consistently check if VLC is installed. I've tried checking registry keys, but they don't seem to be consistent or reliable depending on your Windows version or architecture. Anyone have any suggestions/advice?

Comment: Is there a reason it *needs* to be VLC, and not the default viewer for that file extension?

Comment: @Chris Are you sure the Uninstall folder in registry changes depending on the Windows version/architecture? I think it is always in `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`

Comment: The Uninstall folder doesn't appear to change, but on my computer, I don't have anything relating to VLC in that folder.

Comment: Just checking for the default viewer for the extension might be a viable alternative. I was just hoping there was a good way to check for VLC's install path.

Comment: Did you try `HKLM\Software\VideoLAN\VLC\InstallDir`? You should also handle registry redirection and check both 32-bit and 64-bit hives.

Comment: But if Vlc is installed with no installer you don't have this registry key... So this is a bad idea to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up just checking HKLM\Software\VideoLAN\VLC\ on machines I could find it and giving the user an option in the settings to specify the path to VLC manually if it wasn't detected from that registry value.

Comment: I think that's a reasonable solution. The only users who are going to change VLC from its default path (or remove it once it's been installed as a dependency of your app) are advanced enough that they can reasonably be expected to specify the path themselves.

Comment: On Windows 10 I couldn't find that path, but a similar one in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\VideoLAN\VLC`. Is this system specific?

Comment: I see. That is because I installed a 32-bit version on a 64-bit system.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say you're doing unnecessary work in trying to detect this. What are you going to do if VLC is *not* installed? Show an error message? Then just try to launch it, and show an error message if it fails to launch. That way, you also capture the case where it *is* installed, but still fails to launch for whatever reason. Both are error conditions for your program.

Beyond that, make sure that you include a setup program with your application that automatically installs VLC, since your application requires it to work properly. Then, the only situation where it *wouldn't* be installed (and thus your application would have to show an error message) is if the user explicitly removes it after installation. Since they would have to do so intentionally, it's very unlikely they would be surprised when your application subsequently failed to work.

Comment: The problem is knowing where it is to launch it. It could be in a few different locations depending on the OS and Architecture. Plus, it could vary if they've specified a custom directory.